# Native-base conditional button in header

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have the following header component:

```
class HeaderNav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <Header style={styles.header}>
          <Left>
            <Button
              transparent
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer() }>
              <Icon name="bars" size={25} color="#D35920" />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
                // body content 
          </Body>
          <Right style={styles.headerRight}>
             <Button onPress={() => this.props.doSomething}>
                <Title>{this.props.rightTitle!= null ? this.props.rightTitle}</Title>
             </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>
    )
  }
}
```

And I would like to render the contents in the Right Component based on each screen by stating the title in the constructor as follows:

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          rightTitle: 'Title'    
      }

      this.doSomething= this.doSomething.bind(this);
    }


    doSomething= () => {        
      // logic goes here
    }
```

And then rendering the component:

```
render(){
  return(){
    <HeaderNav />
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you pass `rightTitle` prop to the Header component? How do you render it in your screens?

Comment: @Federkun I have updated my question to include how the component is rendered!

Answer (score 1):

First off, I highly recommend you to study all this state/props thing. If you see your render function, you are not passing any prop to header. Hence, you won't have any rightTitle in your button.

Your render method

```
render(){
  return(){
    <HeaderNav rightTitle="your desired rightTitle"/>
  }
}
```

If you want to use the rightTitle you declared in state:

```
render(){
  return(){
    <HeaderNav rightTitle={this.state.rightTitle}/>
  }
}
```

Then, you will be able to access `this.props.rightTitle` in your `HeaderNav` Component. [See Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props)